# PHP Mysqli how to select data from the last 24hours

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get data added in the last 24 hours I already tried with this query but it shows nothing:

```
$result = $db->query("
    SELECT reclamations.* , customers.*
    FROM reclamations
    LEFT JOIN customers ON reclamations.id_customer = customers.id
    ORDER BY reclamations.code
    WHERE reclamation_date = DATE_SUB( NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR"));
```

Comment: you have syntax error: `"));` should be: `)");`

Comment: no it's not about the syntax, it's just in the question here i forget to delete ")" cause the query's in an "if", but don't worry i get the answer thank you

Comment: I did not mean that the solution resided in the syntax error, just noted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently have a PHP *and* MySQL syntax error because you having a closing parenthesis the wrong side of your closing double-quote.

How about the following, where the column is more than or equal to now minus 1 day:

```
$result = $db->query("
    SELECT reclamations.* , customers.*
    FROM reclamations
    LEFT JOIN customers 
        ON reclamations.id_customer = customers.id
    ORDER BY reclamations.code
    WHERE reclamation_date >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
");
```

Comment: Thank you Goerge. that works correctly i appreciate that

Comment: Glad to have helped @Yassine.

Comment: @Yassine if George responded your question, please accept his answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $db->query("
    SELECT reclamations.* , customers.*
    FROM reclamations
    LEFT JOIN customers ON reclamations.id_customer = customers.id
    ORDER BY reclamations.code
    WHERE reclamation_date BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 HOUR) and NOW()";
```

Comment: You have the order of the times backwards in your `BETWEEN`. The lower value has to be first.

Comment: Draguna thx, but actually it doesn't work, @george code's works

Comment: ok :D I'm sorry it does not work, but I'm glad that your issue is now solved! :)